# pass variables between multiple activities

Tags: java, android

I am programming a calendar. I created several activities:

1. Mainactivity (default) in which there is a data picker and the following code:
   https://codeshare.io/aJxexR
2. ora.activity where there is a timepicker
3. activity_titolo where the user must input the title of the event
4. finally I would like to create an activity that receives all the variables and creates a notification according to the date set by the user.

How do I pass all the data from the first activity to the last and create this notification?

project link https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/15Aom5n6CJwBV8l0H90MypmVTKlAr6FDe?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you considered using bundles to pass data in intents,here is what you have to do

1. create a Parcelable class
2. add it to bundle object and add the object to
   the intent that creates the final activity
3. receive the bundles object from the new
   activity
   here is an example of a Parcelable class

   ```
   public class calender implements 
   Parcelable 
   {
   private String date;
   private String time;

   protected calender(Parcel in) {
   date = in.readString();
   time = in.readString();
   }

   public static final Creator<calender> 
   CREATOR 
   = new Creator<calender>() {
   @Override
   public calender createFromParcel(Parcel 
   in) {
       return new calender(in);
   }

   @Override
   public calender[] newArray(int size) {
       return new calender[size];
   }
   };

   public String getDate() {
   return date;
   }

   public void setDate(String date) {
   this.date = date;
   }

   public String getTime() {
     return time;
   }

   public void setTime(String time) {
   this.time = time;
   }

   @Override
   public int describeContents() {
   return 0;
   }

   @Override
   public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int 
   flags) {
   dest.writeString(date);
   dest.writeString(time);
   }
   }
   ```

and here is how you send the parceble class using
intent

```
    Intent intent=new 
    Intent(CurrentActivty.this,
    finalActivty.class);
    calender calender=new calender();
    calender.setDate("example date");
    calender.setTime("example time");
    Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable("data",calender);
    intent.putExtra("calenderData",bundle);
    startActivity(intent);
```

and then finally you receive the intent data in your onCreate method

```
if (getIntent().getBundleExtra("calenderData")!=null)
    {
        calender calender =getIntent().getBundleExtra("calenderData").getParcelable("data");
       //do something with the calender variable
    }
```

[here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle) is documentation on class bundle